# Same user on multiple domains

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, migration, active-directory

We have a SharePoint 2010 server. Since the start, we only had 1 domain. Now, company has decided to move some users on another domain. These users will not actually be moved, they will be created as a new user in the new domain and their previous domain ID will remain active for an year or so.

When doing so, SharePoint is treating the user in both domains as different. I want to preserve history, permissions, etc. associated to the user irrespective of the fact whether he logs in from previous domain or the new domain id.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of SharePoint they are two separate users. What you should do is establish domain trust and not create two accounts for the users. Then later if you decide to migrate the domains you can also migrate the users in SharePoint and you will retain thier history. The path you chose will make this significantly harder.

You can try to Move-SPUser now, but without some planning it may not work in this case.